# How to disable WordPress to put P tags?

Tags: theme-development

I have tried everything from installing plugins and adding codes in `functions.php` but nothing prevented to add P tags in WordPress site.

```
/* Remove empty p tags */
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

This tag didn't work.

```
//Removes all empty p tags
$('p:empty').remove();
```

This tag worked but only removed empty P tags. Others remain same.

What did I miss?

Comment: Thanks Ethan for the edit. But, I m still struggling to find the solution. :-(

Comment: Are you trying to disable the addition of all `<p>` tags, or are you trying to get rid of empty `<p></p>` tags?

Answer (score 1):

Those are the correct filters.

Make sure you're adding them to the active theme's `functions.php` file.

Update: Removed filter suggestion based on comment below.

Comment: Hi cowgill, thanks for that. still it remains same.

Comment: `<p><!-- Donate today block begins --></p>` It remains like this.

Comment: I am assuming may be some plugin is conflicting with this. I can't figure this out.

Comment: Disable all your plugins and try again.

Comment: downvoted, as this just do not do what you think it does. `remove_filter` **has** to be called with the exact same priority (and number of parameters) as was used in `add_filter`. Using any other parameters just do nothing.

Comment: Whoops. My mind was thinking `add_action`. Thx for the correction, @Mark Kaplun.